# cannot execute Bash.rc for anaconda installation

Tags: bash

when i used: '''source .bashrc'''  to run '''bashrc''' after installation of anaconda  file it showed [command not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DG85C.png)

'''
'''

Comment: It looks to me like you are trying to source `.bashrc` into a `zsh` shell

Comment: Invoke it as `bash -x ~/.bashrc` to see details.